# Rows Added/Removed event? (Infragistics Wingrid)

Tags: .net, winforms, infragistics

I need to update the Row Count on a label near the WinGrid (WinForms project).

The Grid update is made in different ways - datasource change, manual adds/removs, sql initialisations, etc.

Is there a universal event raised when the Grid changes the row number (datasource change including)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I manually identified where I add the rows to the grid, and updated coresspondingly the count label.

So, I didn't used Grid events.

Answer (score 3):

I assume that you are binding to a list that has change notifications like a BindingList or a DataSet/DataTable.  This has to be true if you add items to the data source and they show up in the grid as the grid relies on events from the data source to know it needs to update.

In that case you can bind to the ListChanged event of the list that your grid is bound to. This event is part of the [IBindingList interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ibindinglist.aspx).

If you are binding to a DataTable/DataSet, then you will want to use the event exposed by the DefaultView of the DataTable since this is what implements IBindingList and what the grid actually binds to.

If you are using a collection that implements INotifyCollectionChanged rather than IBindingList then you would use the CollectionChanged event.  This would be more likely if you were doing WPF development as this is what an ObservableCollection uses for change notifications.

Comment: And this will be true also for the filtering actions?

Comment: If you are using filtering then this wouldn't update in that case because the DataSource isn't changed.  If that is a requirement, then you could use the ListChanged event and the grids AfterRowFilterChanged event and then call a method from each that would update the Label

Answer (score 0):

In my experience no, there isn't a global event that will be called when the rows number changes.
My best solution for this is a generic method that will be called from the various events that could modify the number of displayed rows.

Something like this

```
private void UpdateRowsCount(UltraGrid grd, string messageFmt = "Rows count: {0}")
{
    labelRowCount.Text = string.Format(messageFmt, grd.Rows.FilteredInRowCount);
}
```

then the events that should be handled:

- grd_AfterRowFilterChanged // don't forget this if you have filtering enabled
- grd_AfterRowsDeleted
- grd_AfterRowInsert

and, of course, after setting the datasource.

```
 grd.DataSource = myDataTable;
 this.UpdateRowsCount(grd, "Customers count: {0}");
```

If someone  has a better knowledge of the problem, I will be very interested in a different approach.

Comment: unfortunately "AfterRowInsert" is not fired when datasource changes..., nor when rows are added manually (grid.Rows.Add(...))

Comment: There is an interesting thread on Infragistics forum about AfterRowInsert not fired. Hope it helps.  http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/t/8218.aspx

Comment: If the grid shows changes from the data source then the list the grid is bound to will have change notifications and you can use the relevant event.  For lists that implement IBindingList it is the ListChanged event.  I have provided more detail in an alternate answer.